# Autofill login form Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I didn't find a way for the browser to autofill the login and password in the Keycloak login form

[image]

Has anyone been interested and solved this issue?

At the same time, it does work on http, but not on https.
When I try to manually add to the password manager, I get an error message in the browser console:

[image]

By replacing "autofill =off" with "=on" in the HTML file, the browser will display a list of selecting only the user name

Comment: After assigning dns and issuing the certificate, the problem went away.